# Changed Jenkins port doesn't applied

Tags: jenkins

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and Jenkins 1.3.3
I need to change the local Jenkins port from 8080 to 8888.

I tried to change the config file `sudo gedit /etc/default/jenkins` in the string

```
#port for HTTP connector (default 8080; disable with -1)
HTTP_PORT=8888
```

After restart service: `sudo service jenkins start` it doesn't affect changes. I still visit jenkins with 8080 port.

Also in this config file I add additional string: `JENKINS_ARGS="--httpPort=$HTTP_PORT"` but unfortunately after restart service the same - 8080.

I tried to change the address via web interface in the `Manage Jenkins` next `Configure System` next change string `Jenkins URL` to `http://0.0.0.0:8888/` and apply and restart service. I visited page `http://0.0.0.0:8080/cli/command/who-am-i` and have got next features:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://0.0.0.0:8888/ -webSocket who-am-i
Reports your credential and permissions.
```

So changes are saved but doesn't affect. I tried to restart my PC to initial all changes.
Can You help me? Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to `sudo service jenkins stop` *before*`sudo service jenkins start`  to achieve a "restart".

Comment: sure, I use SUDO and firstly I stop service and then start (or use restart service)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to the documentations in:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#debianubuntu

It says that you can modify by:

```
systemctl edit jenkins
```

Then add the following lines:

> [Service] Environment="JENKINS_PORT=8888"

Port should be your desired port to use. Save it and then restart jenkins:

```
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```

Answer (score 2):

If jenkins installed as linux service, open the file /usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service,search for the content  "Environment="JENKINS_PORT=8080". Change the port number to your desired. Execute the commands

`systemctl daemon-reload` 
 `systemctl restart jenkins.service`
`

 
Access the jenkins in browser with the new port number